# Internet Explorer doesn't resolve DNS properly

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, internet-explorer, citrix

I have a weird issue with users. We are using Citrix XenApp. Users have to login through a portal. Lets call it portal.example.com. They can do this both at the company or from home.

If a user starts up with the company laptop from home it works fine. Until after that they return to the company network. They receive a 404 error from Internet Explorer. The only fix until now is to reset all settings to default in IE11.

After some investigation the following has been found.

- Resolving the DNS name in the company LAN returns the correct IP address.
- Visiting the portal on the IP address works fine.
- Resetting only the security settings to default doesn't fix it.
- Resetting only privacy settings doens't fix it.
- Resetting SSL Cert states doesn't fix it.
- Removing automatic proxy settings doesn't fix it

Does anyone have any idea what the problem can be?
I'm still going to try installing FireFox for the next user who gets the problem to see if IE11 bugs

Comment: Citix is a company, which of their products are you talking about.

Comment: Sry, I mean XenApp

Comment: What are you publishing? Full desktop? Or IExplore.exe? If full desktop, do you get weird resolution for the name as well? Test this using both `nslookup.exe` `ping.exe -a`. Also: "404" means not "i couldn't resolve that name", instead 404 means "yes, I am indeed a web server, but sorry, I do not have that specific page". So you are reaching *some* web server at least.

Comment: Oke in that not I don't get a 404 from the webserver. I get the page cannot be displayed from IE. We are publishing a full desktop.

Comment: To add. Even Google Chrome gives the same issue

Comment: @s.lenders So you use the same URL to log in but it has two different IP-adresses? Are you referring to Storefront? Are you referring to Netscaler? Or both?

Comment: @Tom Within the LAN it has only 1 private IP. from the internet it has 1 public adres. It's not storefront but traffic from internet passes through netscaler if I'm correct

Comment: @s.lenders But the same URL right? Please check if you are using Storefront. Because in my experience your problem is most likely the Netscaler or beacon configuration on Storefront.

Comment: Same URL indeed. I'll check it